# Detect Roof shapes

Tags: arcgis-pro, rooftop-building

I need to be able to determine roof shapes in a specific area. I already found the course as provided by ESRI (https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/extract-roof-forms-for-municipal-development/), but manually editing buildings with different roof shapes takes up too much time for my dataset, as there are around 100.000 buildings in it.

I have building data (shapefile) and I have acces to .lasd data. I want to be able to determine if roofs are flat or not (angled for example). Does anyone has tips on how to tackle or solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange. Did you try running through the tutorial you linked? That does what you asked. You only need to manually edit if there are errors in the input building footprints. It is also pretty accurate, at least for flat vs gable/hip from personal experience.

Answer (score 3):

Take all the las points over a defined roof. Apply a setback of one meter or so and use just these points. Calculate the mean and standard deviation of the roof elevation points. If the standard deviation is within about 50cm of the mean then it is most likely flat. Any more than this and it is likely, not flat. You can always calculate slopes as well. Chimneys and antennas will throw you off as will other items on flat roofs such as commercial air conditioning units etc.

This paper lays out the ESRI process https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0198971509000805